# How to encrypt core data sqlite database?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, core-data, encryption

I am creating a cocoa base core data application. I would like to protect the sqlite database, prevent to read it out of the application. How?

Comment: AFAIK, all you can do is install your own copy of SqlCipher and skip using Core Data.

Comment: iPhone can automatically encrypt any file. The downside is that you can no longer use those files on background.

Comment: I am talking about Cocoa development, so implementing for Mac, not for iOS, not for iPhone.

Comment: @János - Doesn't much matter -- could be Android or Windows and the answers would be essentially the same.

Comment: I was relating this saying: "iPhone can automatically encrypt any file.", this is not iPhone, so it is not automatically encrypted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use cipher algorithms to encrypt the database and decrypt when you use it in your app. CommonCrypto or SecurityTransform may be your choice. Take a look at the [Cryptographic Services Guide Apple Dev-Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html).
The needed credentials could be stored securely in the OS X keychain.
So the user could per app start/login decrypt the database and on leave or something, encrypt it.
Another way could be to hardcode the credentials (maybe not a good idea, depends on the security standard you want to use by your app) and do the en-/decrypt on the fly per read/write into the database, so that the database itself is not encrypted but the records in it are. That could be more fault tolerant if your app crashes.

So there is no "right" way to do the task, it depends on what you want to archive and how secure the data has to be.
But what ever you do, don't save any credentials in the *NSUserDefaults*, that is absolutely insecure.
That would be like to have a secured chest and the key for it lays right on the chest.

Comment: Decrypting the entire file when opening the app is quite insecure, as is encrypting/decrypting individual rows.  Only a block encryption scheme similar to SqlCipher is secure beyond the point of simply being window dressing.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree to SqlCipher, but it is also task depended.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree to SqlCipher, but... Also SqlCiper uses OpenSSL wich is secure but does not have always a stable API from version to version. (Source: Apple, own experiences) This is also why other solutions should also be considered, based on the Task.

Comment: You can make your own version of SqlCipher that utilizes the platform's built-in encryption facilities.  This is generally the safest (and it meets US export guidelines).

Comment: Do note that fixing up your own version of SqlCypher, while not a particularly difficult task overall, requires decent programming skills and a fair amount of testing.  It's not a simple matter of "plugging in" one cypher API in place of another.  (It would be nice if someone would do this for the Apple platforms and release it as open source.)

Answer (score 0):

For the iOS side there is is the `Project iMas`-`encrypted-core-data` on [github](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data). It might help you on Cocoa, too.

Aim of the project is to:

> Provides a Core Data store that encrypts all data that is persisted. Besides the initial setup, the usage is exactly the same as Core Data and can be used in existing projects that use Core Data.

Under the hood they use SQLCipher and wrap the coreData methods into sql. So you get an encrypted storage but can use coreData syntax for accessing. No need to know about SQL syntax.

The project looks rather promising. It is definitely worth a look.